# Як називати хрещеного батька свого хресника?

Tags: розмовна-українська, одним-словом

В народі (просторічне), люди, що хрестили ту саму дитину - хресні батьки - називають одне одного теж кумами... Але, по факту, кумами між собою є батьки хресника/хресниці та хрещені батьки. Як правильно називати, наприклад, хрещеного батька тієї самої дитини, яку хрестила я? Теж "кум"?

> Наукове визначення слова "кум": куми, як правило, іменують хресних
> батьків дитини, тобто тих, хто тримав його над купіллю під час
> здійснення Таїнства і приносив обіцянки.
>
> Кум, кума́ — хрещений батько (мати) по відношенню до батьків хрещеника
> та хрещеної матері (батька).
>
> 1. Хрещений батько по відношенню до батьків хрещеника і до хрещеної матері; батько дитини по відношенню до хрещеного батька і хрещеної
>    матері. Був у нього.. приятель, цилюрик, та ще й Марусин кум, вона в
>    нього аж трьох діточок хрестила (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 82);
>    [Ковшик:] Опишіть, будь ласка, мого кума. Коли хочете, я вам про нього
>    таке розкажу... (Олександр Корнійчук, II, 1955, 209); Жили в лугах та
>    ярах віками. Кого не візьми — рідня: кум, сват, брат, племінник
>    (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 369).   Куми — кум і кума разом. — Неси
>    ж [дитину] в хату, а я верхи Кинусь за кумами в Городище... (Тарас
>    Шевченко, I, 1951, 314); Стрічні куми — перші зустрічні, яких
>    запрошують бути кумами. — Ви б, Олексію Івановичу, стрічних кумів
>    узяли, — радять йому добрі приятелі (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 22);
>    Просити (кликати) в куми — запрошувати бути кумом або кумою. — Я тебе
>    до себе в куми прошу... Чув? У куми! Бог послав мені сина. Прошу тебе
>    охрестити (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 225); Хто не чув її .. пісень на
>    весіллях та артільних святах? Хто не кликав її у куми? (Григорій
>    Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 425).

Answer (score 4):

Ви самі дали відповідь на своє запитання: "Кум, кума́ — хрещений батько (мати) по відношенню до батьків хрещеника та **хрещеної матері (батька)**". [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/kum) подає аналогічне визначення.
**Отже робимо висновок, що хрещений батько Вашого хрещеника Ваш *кум***.

Comment: Питання було про хрещеного батька її похресника, а не біологічного батька похресника.